# How to perform onPause() on ActivityClassB untill it came back to ActivityClassB from ActivityClassC

Tags: android

I am developing a web application, in this I have 3(A, B and C) classes. How can I Pause an Activity 'B'(which contain a Specializations list) while going to Activity 'C'(which contain a Doctors list), and again I want to go back to Activity 'B' from Activity 'C', when I pressed custom back button which is in Activity 'C.'. And The data which is presented in the Activity 'B' should be available in 'B' Activity, but it is not displaying the values. It is is opening the Activity 'B' with empty screen.

thanks
Userq1

Answer (score 0):

when you start a new activity, your previous activity automatically calls `onPause()`

but when it returns, it calls `onResume()` and/or `onActivityResult`. So handle your updates in either methods